# Upgrade Angular 4 to 10: Error cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies

Tags: angular, angular10

I'm new with upgrading the angular platform and trying to do upgrade in angular from 4 to 10 and followed the instructions given in the angular's official page

https://update.angular.io/?v=4.4-10.0

currently, I'm stuck in upgrading it to angular 6 because of this error:

```
Error: Cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies. Package @angular/core would need to match both versions "7.2.16" and "10.1.2, which are not compatible.
Cannot update safely because packages have conflicting dependencies. Package @angular/core would need to match both versions "7.2.16" and "10.1.2, which are not compatible.
```

does anybody have solution on this?

I've tried to browse for this error but I couldn't find one fit to my problem

Comment: You should probably update your Angular project slowly by each major version instead of updating from v4 to v10 straight-away.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have some packages that are depending on those versions of @angular/core. What I would do is search inside your `node_modules` folder for matches to `7.2.16` and `10.1.2` and see if anything lists "@angular/core" with those versions as dependencies.